# how to convert "12A,13B,14C" to [12A,13B,14C] in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like below.

sections = "12A,13B,14C"

But I need `[12A, 13B, 14C]` for future use. How to create array from above string?

Comment: I think you need `sections.split(',') `

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Use split method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **[split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method** for that to split your string data into array values, have a look to updated code

```js
  var sections = "12A,13B,14C";
  sections = sections.split(',');
  console.log(sections);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help! Just use **split** method of JS.

```js
  sections = "12A,13B,14C"
  let array = sections.split(',');
  console.log(array)
```